# Email template for mailgun + node.js

Tags: node.js, email, templates, mailgun

I'm building an app using node.js + express and using mailgun as my email service. I wanted to check if anyone knows how to make templates that I could use in the email body?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I create my mail messages from templates inside an express application using the [render method of the express application](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render). This way i keep my mail templates inside the application template hierarchy and can use the same template engine and re-usability patterns. Currently my express application use Jade as template engine.

Comment: i see.. could you explain to me how you pass your template to the mailgun email body?

Comment: I use nodemailer with the [mailgun transport](https://github.com/orliesaurus/nodemailer-mailgun-transport).

Comment: This works well in a Sails application too when using sails.hooks.http.app to get to the underlying HTTP server.